# Getting the same instance of RandomAccessFile in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, immutability, randomaccessfile, clojure-java-interop

This piece of code runs on the server and it detects the changes to a file and sends it to the client. This is working for the first time and after that the file length is not getting updated even the I changed the file and saved it. I guess the clojure immutability is the reason here. How can I make this work?

```
 (def clients (atom {}))
    (def rfiles (atom {}))
    (def file-pointers (atom {}))

(defn get-rfile [filename]
  (let [rdr ((keyword filename) @rfiles)]
    (if rdr
      rdr
      (let [rfile (RandomAccessFile. filename "rw")]
        (swap! rfiles assoc (keyword filename) rfile)
        rfile))))

(defn send-changes [changes]
  (go (while true
        (let [[op filename] (<! changes)
              rfile (get-rfile filename)
              ignore (println (.. rfile getChannel size))
              prev ((keyword filename) @file-pointers)
              start (if prev prev 0)
              end (.length rfile) // file length is not getting updated even if I changed the file externally
              array (byte-array (- end start))]
          (do
            (println (str "str" start " end" end))
            (.seek rfile start)
            (.readFully rfile array)
            (swap! file-pointers assoc (keyword filename) end)
            (doseq [client @clients]
              (send! (key client) (json/write-str
                                    {:changes  (apply str (map char array))
                                     :fileName filename}))
              false))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no immutability here. In the `rfiles` atom, you store standard Java objects that *are* mutable.

This code works well only if data are *appended* to the end of the file, and the size is always increasing.

If there is an update/addition (of length +N) in the file other than at the end, the *pointers* `start` and `end` won't point to the modified data, but just to the last N characters and you will send dummy stuff to the clients.

If there is a delete or any change that decrease the length,

```
array (byte-array (- end start))
```

will throw a `NegativeArraySizeException` you don't see (eaten by the `go` bloc?). You can add some `(try (...) catch (...))` or test that `(- end start)` is alway positive or null, to manage it and do the appropriate behaviour: resetting the pointers?,...

Are you sure the files you scan for changes are only changed by appending data? If not, you need to handle this case by resetting or updating the pointers accordingly.

I hope it will help.

---

**EDIT** test environment.

I defined the following. There is no change to the code you provided.

```
;; define the changes channel
(def notif-chan (chan))

;; define some clients
(def clients (atom {:foo "foo" :bar "bar"}))

;; helper function to post a notif of change in the channel
(defn notify-a-change [op filename]
  (go (>! notif-chan [op filename])))

;; mock of the send! function used in send-changes
(defn send! [client message]
  (println client message))

;; main loop
(defn -main [& args]
  (send-changes notif-chan))
```

in a repl, I ran:

```
repl> (-main)
```

in a shell (I tested with an editor too):

```
sh> echo 'hello there' >> ./foo.txt
```

in the repl:

```
repl> (notify-a-change "x" "./foo.txt")
str0 end12
:bar {"changes":"hello there\n","fileName":".\/foo.txt"}
:foo {"changes":"hello there\n","fileName":".\/foo.txt"}

repl> (notify-a-change "x" "./foo.txt")
str12 end12
:bar {"changes":"","fileName":".\/foo.txt"}
:foo {"changes":"","fileName":".\/foo.txt"}
```

in a shell:

```
sh> echo 'bye bye' >> ./foo.txt
```

in a repl:

```
repl> (notify-a-change "x" "./foo.txt")
str12 end20
:bar {"changes":"bye bye\n","fileName":".\/foo.txt"}
:foo {"changes":"bye bye\n","fileName":".\/foo.txt"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sure I am appending the data at the end of the file. This code sends the appended changes to the client if I make a new RandomAccessFile each time rather than caching file object. (println (str "str" start " end" end)) tells me that once the File is created its size stays the same. So I thought may be get-rfile always giving a new copy.

Comment: I tested the code locally, and when I append some data to the file (e.g. `echo "hello" >> ./foo.txt` or with an editor), and then I post a change to the `changes` channel, the change is detected and log the right information. And when I repeat the process, it works fine. I don't think the problem comes from the `get-rfile` or `file-pointers` **if** no other process is messing around with the datafile...

Comment: Thats interesting. I'm using TextEdit for this. I'll try using a different editor and will see if that makes any difference. (I dont think it will).

Comment: How are you able post the changes to channel when you update the file in a different process? Can you please share your piece of code.

Comment: It this point I do it manually from the repl: 1.update the file, 2.post the change. I don't know how you do this in your system since the code does not contain this part.